# How to hide the div of heading if condition is true

Tags: php

I just want to hide the div "List of dashboard blocks that are available to your dashboard." if the $check==0

```
<div id="heading" style="display:block">List of dashboard blocks that are available to your dashboard.</div>

if ($check == 0) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td> <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">All blocks are already added into the dashboard</div></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }
        ?>
```

Comment: `if ($check > 0){ div }else{  tr }`

Comment: You are missing `<?php` before `if ($check == 0) {`

Comment: <?php tag is there

Comment: @khalid Junaid that is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
 <?php 
     if ($check == 0) { 
         $hideDiv = 'style="display:none"';
     }else{ 
         $hideDiv = 'style="display:block"';
     }
 ?>
<div id="heading" <?php echo $hideDiv; ?> >List of dashboard blocks that are available to your dashboard.</div>
<tr>
    <td> 
       <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">All blocks are already added into the dashboard</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the open and close tags for PHP.

I also recommend using short if statement like I used below so you don't chase that one "}" across the templates, but you can see it clearly marked as "endif"

```
<div id="heading" style="display:block">List of dashboard blocks that are available to your dashboard.</div>
<?php if ($check == 0) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td> 
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">All blocks are already added into the dashboard</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After edit I think you just want to hide the first line, in which case, you can inline the check with shorthand if echo statement

```
<div id="heading" style="display:<?= $check == 0 ? 'none':  'block' ?>">List of dashboard blocks that are available to your dashboard.</div>
```